# Strange folders are automaticaly created in my C:\ drive

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Updates Folders (With Strange Names) in C drive](https://superuser.com/questions/130125/windows-updates-folders-with-strange-names-in-c-drive)

I don't know what are they and if it's ok to delete them.
These are the folders:

[image]

These are the files that each of the folders contains:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*edit: as per comments below, these are of course temp files, not rollback files as I incorrectly stated*
WRONG: These files are kept in case you want to roll back a windows update. Depending on how likely it is that you would ever want to do that and how old these files already are, you could probably bin them.

Comment: Rollback information is stored in `%SystemRoot%\$NtUninstallKB<id>$`. These are just temp files.

Comment: Since Windows 98 that kind of strange folders are created in drive root...

Answer (score 4):

Those folders are where Windows Updates are unpacked before installation. Usually they are removed automatically, but if they aren't - reboot (to make sure) and delete them yourself.