# Strange directory under C: of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Updates Folders (With Strange Names) in C drive](https://superuser.com/questions/130125/windows-updates-folders-with-strange-names-in-c-drive)

I have a folder named "ed6b7b66d9c1d645bfce0f8b33c3" under C: of Windows 7. I was wondering what its purpose is and if it is safe to delete? Thanks!

It takes up 120 MB. Its content is as follows:
[image]

Comment: The answers have all got this right.  I would point out that some MS updates will act funny if you delete these folders THEN try to uninstall them (although I'm not aware of any that would actually be broken or anything that severe)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Googled the **KBxxxxxx** numbers, shows that the folder contains a .NET Framework setup.

It is safe to delete as it is solely an installer...

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is safe to delete, those odd numbered folders on the root of C are leftovers from Microsoft patches, upgrades or installers, sometimes they do not get cleaned up when it is done installing.

It appears it was left over from a Microsoft NET framework installer

Answer (score 3):

Looks like setup files of an application. Some setup applications extract themselves to a directory and start the installation from that location. That's one of them. Start setup.exe to find out what it is. If you have the original setup then you can safely delete.