# Windows Vista C: Drive

Tags: windows-vista, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Updates Folders (With Strange Names) in C drive](https://superuser.com/questions/130125/windows-updates-folders-with-strange-names-in-c-drive)

What are the directories on the C: drive that have odd names like "e0b21d8c70609853dc"?  Can I delete them?

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate.  I suppose I can delete this one then.

Answer (score 3):

These directories are usually temporary directories created by patches, service packs or other installers.

If they contain no files inside, they are safe to delete.

If they contain files, they may be safe to delete (especially if they only contain text log files), however, I personally prefer to just leave them.