# what is "cd4f11d23e3716b84c14abcfeaea" and how did it get installed?

Tags: windows-7, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Updates Folders (With Strange Names) in C drive](https://superuser.com/questions/130125/windows-updates-folders-with-strange-names-in-c-drive)
>   [What are these folders created on my Western Digital 2TB Mirror?](https://superuser.com/questions/382305/what-are-these-folders-created-on-my-western-digital-2tb-mirror)

**Mystery**: Two nights ago, a 20GB file appeared on an almost empty *non-OS* drive in my computer. I did not install or download it. It has appeared in a drive I only normally use for backups. It will not let me erase it. It has the title `cd4f11d23e3716b84c14abcfeaea`
I can open it but I can't open any of the sub folders. Here is what it looks like when I open it[image: capture of files within mystery file made with snipping tool]

Can anyone tell me if this is malicious and if so how I can remove it?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are these folders created on my Western Digital 2TB Mirror?](http://superuser.com/questions/382305/what-are-these-folders-created-on-my-western-digital-2tb-mirror) and/or [Windows Updates Folders (With Strange Names) in C drive](http://superuser.com/questions/130125/windows-updates-folders-with-strange-names-in-c-drive)

Comment: This issue is so annoying since its so difficult to google it, unless the stars align and your hash matches someone elses hash

Comment: What does `SplashScreen.bmp` look like? this can usually tell you what it is

Answer (score 6):

This is a security update from Microsoft, why it install to your backup drive may do with available space:

> http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27017

Comment: this is most likely correct. And you should be able to just delete it through command prompt or after a restart

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes MS software updates fail to remove the temporary directories created during install. You can safely remove it.

Answer (score 2):

This is from file name NDP40-KB2539636 identified as a [.NET 4.0 security update (KB2539636)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2539636). From this, you can find the bulletin number and [look it up for further ID (MS11-069)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms11-069)

The name of the directory is a guid assigned for the install and is where the update has been uncompressed for install.

On Windows XP, the update would create a log file with the KB2539636 identifier in your C:/Windows folder.

Any time you see these KB numbers, it's fairly easy to look up the patch and bulletin info.

As to why it's on this drive, if you look in your System Restore settings, you probably will find that System Restore is also using this drive for its backups. Any drives thus identified with free space are fair game for Windows to create a temporary direcory for use in uncompressing system updates before their application to the OS.

As a cross reference, in Windows 7 **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Update\View**, update history will show an entry referencing KB2539636, its imporance, install status and day installed.