# How do such folders get created?

Tags: windows-7

I refreshed the documents in my E: drive and suddenly out of nowhere, a file named 8878cd326b93e32d8c gets created. And it requires administrative permission to open. What is this folder and how did it come? Is it a virus?

Comment: These are usually created by installers, most often by Windows Update for drivers. In any case, these are not a virus.

Comment: From what I observed, these folders are simply created on the drive with the largest free space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Updates Folders (With Strange Names) in C drive](https://superuser.com/questions/130125/windows-updates-folders-with-strange-names-in-c-drive)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/388648/what-is-cd4f11d23e3716b84c14abcfeaea-and-how-did-it-get-installed?rq=1