# Western Digital 1TB Hard Drive with Randomly Named Folders That I Can't Access or Delete

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, windows-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random directories in c:\ that I cannot delete](https://superuser.com/questions/132176/random-directories-in-c-that-i-cannot-delete)

I recently purchased a 1 TB Western Digital hard drive and today my laptop did 20 updates before shutting down. When I turned the computer back on something unusual happened, it said something about 20 000 something updates which finished within a minute or so.

I had a look in my storage device and it now has a randomly named folder I didn't create that has loads of similarly named folders within it that I need an administrators permission to access.  I am the administrator but I don't know how to allow myself in, either way I clicked and passed that but I now need a SYSTEM allowance to get into all these sub-folders.

The only Google result related to this problem was [this question here](https://superuser.com/questions/382305/what-are-these-folders-created-on-my-western-digital-2tb-mirror) on Super User.

The two answers conflict as to whether or not I can delete folder safely and I obviously can't do anything as I am not allowed.

Is it safe to delete these folders and how do I go about doing so?

Comment: If you have trouble deleting the folder, see http://superuser.com/a/423821/96662

Comment: Do you have a antivirus. As I think you have folder virus. please name some of the folders you have now...

Answer (score 1):

The folders are just a cache for windows updates, and you can delete the folder. To do so, you must get permission.

1. Right click on the folder
2. Select properties
3. Click the security tab
4. Click edit
5. Click add
6. Click advanced
7. Find your username
8. Click OK
9. Grant yourself full control
10. Make sure to click apply.

Then delete should work.

Comment: @Roni - You might have to perform this command to all folders and sub-folders.

Comment: There is a checkbox for that.